# What is the easiest (correct) way to reset/reinitialize/restart the view of a UIViewController on button click?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a simple game (without game engine, such as Cocos2d) in a UiViewController and when I lose I  have a button for restarting the game.

So, what I have is

```
    - (IBAction) restart:(id)sender {
        \\Some incorrect way of reseting my view
    }
```

I have tried

```
    - (IBAction) restart:(id)sender {
        [self viewDidLoad];
    }
```

but then there is several copies of the graphics appearing in my view...
What is the correct way to implement this method?

Note: I'm using ARC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as if this is a single view application.  With that assumption, would you be able to create a restart method and in this method you simply check to see if variables and values are initialized, have values, or not created.  You would check to see if you need to create your variables or simply reset them and create a "begin" state.

I would intend to use this method to first initialize and start the game by calling the method from inside of viewDidLoad, and call that reset method to clear the game when you intend to reset.  You don't want to use `viewDidLoad` as this is only intended to be run when the view is initialized and loads the first time.

Answer (score 0):

As you've discovered, `viewDidLoad:` is intended to be called by the app framework, not your code.

The answer to your question really depends on the logic of your game.  A view doesn't know how to reset itself except to the degree that you tell it what to display as its starting state.

Comment: Is in not possible to dump all of the graphics and reload the View as if it were called "from the beginning". So I have to reset all the variables and the view manually?

Comment: You could possibly remove the view and create a new instance of it but that isn't the simplest thing if the original view was created in a xib or storyboard.  A better idea would be to have one view controller with a menu and a second one with your game view.  The second one would be created when you clicked "Play" on the menu and removed when an individual game was finished.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go back to the beginning, then you should create a new instance of your view controller (which will recreate its views from scratch). The button's action method would need to be connected to whatever class initially instantiated your view controller. How to do that exactly, depends on the structure of your app.